# ¿Qué me falta en este código que es para una aplicacion web para solicitar las ventas de los productos de una tienda online?

Tags: javascript, api, http

¿Qué me falta en este código que es para una aplicacion web para solicitar las ventas de los productos de una tienda online? Estoy desarrolando una aplicacion web simple para una logistica para ecommerce que maneja una cantidad menor de pedidos por día.

```
class Ui {
    constructor() {
        this.baseURL = 'https://api.tiendacliente.com'; // URL base de la API de tus clientes
    }

    async obtenerProductosVendidos() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${this.baseURL}/productos_vendidos`);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Error al obtener los productos vendidos');
            }
            const productos = await response.json();
            return productos;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Hubo un error:', error);
        }
    }

    async mostrarProductosVendidos() {
        const productos = await this.obtenerProductosVendidos();
        if (productos) {
            productos.forEach(producto => {
                this.agregarProducto(producto);
            });
        }
    }

    agregarProducto(producto) {
        const productoLista = document.getElementById('producto-lista');
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = `
            <div class = "card text-center mb-4">
                <div class = "card-body">
                    <strong>Orden</strong>: ${producto.orden}
                    <strong>Nombre</strong>: ${producto.nombre}
                    <strong>Dirección</strong>: ${producto.direccion}
                    <strong>Localidad</strong>: ${producto.localidad}
                    <strong>Codigo Postal</strong>: ${producto.codigoPostal}
                    <strong>Contacto</strong>: ${producto.contacto}
                    <strong>Nota</strong>: ${producto.nota}
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
        productoLista.appendChild(element);
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te falta.. hacerlo?? tu pregunte no se entiende, cual es el problema???